# Problem with command `-exec'

Tags: command-line, bash, lubuntu

I am quite new to Ubuntu shell and I wrote a short command for taking my files names but unfortunately I got problem with the `-exec` command. When I run the following code:

```
samples=$(find . -name "*_1.fastq.gz" -exec basename \{} cut -d _ -f1-2\)
```

I get the error

> find: missing argument to `-exec'

I know I am probably missing a character or so but I couldn't figure it. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to terminate the "exec" command with an explicit semi-colon or plus

Answer (score 3):

If I had to guess, you look to be wanting the find to print out the basenames of the files.  You then want to pass that to cut to only get up to the second underscore.  Is that accurate?

If so, you are missing a few characters.  I believe your command should be as follows:

```
samples=$(find . -name "*_1.fastq.gz" -exec basename {} \; | cut -d _ -f1-2\)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yest! so I actually want to get rid of _1.fas..... . but now the following code return a parenthesis error. unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'

Comment: The final `)` should not be escaped. Also if you want to remove the whole `_1.fastq.gz` extension you can pass that as a suffix parameter to `basename` i.e. `find . -name "*_1.fastq.gz" -exec basename {} "_1.fastq.gz" \;` rather than trying to use `cut`

Comment: Yeah.  My bad.  Didn't realize I had an extra backslash in there.